# JSR 303 vs Spring validation

Tags: spring, bean-validation, spring-validator, jsr

I am new to Spring validation. Recently I have been exploring different approaches of validation utilities available in Spring. I found there are basically two approaches: 1. with JSR-303 and 2. by implementing Validator interface in Spring.

What I understood, with first approach one can achieve model level validation whereas the latter is more appropriate to validate String, Integer types of inputs. Is there something more, that I am missing here?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an open source alternative to JSR-303.

This solution can perform all validation of the request message, but no hassle coding is required.

https://github.com/ckpoint/CheckPoint

With Check-Point, all validation is possible without further code, just by changing the annotation of the Controller method.

After that, all validation settings can be easily made in Admin Page.

I think this video can help your understand. https://youtu.be/I1aEIztXlhE

[Check-Point Admin-Page Setting Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuYUT.png)